# VMware Workstation 8 host-only networks

Tags: networking, vmware-workstation

I need some help how to use the host-only networks of VMware Worstation 8 - I can't reach my Vm from my host, though I have selected host-only as network adapter type.

I already googled and checked the Workstation 8 help, but there are no hints for beginners, how to configure it. Which IP does the VM need? (Can't use DHCP inside the VM for some reasons). What do I have to change on the host itself? Do I understand it correct, that the traffic between the host and the VM won't leave my computer, so a hardware firewall isn't relevant / nothing needs to be changed on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something was wrong with my interface. Resetted the network stuff in vmwares virtual network editor. then I checked the vmnet1 interafce, it had 2 ips assigned, one is correct, at the other I have no clue where it comes from. anyway, now it works :-)

Comment: Mark this as the answer please.

Comment: marked as correct answer ;-)